# Using terminal to reset icon cache - which method?

Tags: command-line, osx, cache, icons

I've been trying to find out how to reset the icon cache on my MacBook, and two methods seem to always be suggested. However, the two approaches differ slightly in the third line.

**Method 1**

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo mv /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store com.apple.ic
```

**Method 2**

```
sudo find /private/var/folders/ \ -name com.apple.dock.iconcache -exec rm {} \;
sudo find /private/var/folders/ \ -name com.apple.iconservices -exec rm -rf {} \;
sudo rm -rf /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
```

I don't like doing anything in terminal unless I understand what it does.

Therefore...what do these two approaches essentially do - and what is the effect of the difference on line three? Is one method better than the other?

Answer (score 0):

The `mv` command moves `/Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store` to `com.apple.ic` in the current directory. That means that the data is kept around, but since it is no longer present in the place where the system looks for it, it stops having any effect. The name `com.apple.ic` isn't anything special, you can pick another name if you want.

You can undo this by moving the data back, but only if the system hasn't started writing anything to the cache yet:

```
sudo mv com.apple.ic /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store
```

(This needs to be performed from the same [working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory). By default, when you open a terminal, the working directory is your home directory.)

If the system has already recreated `/Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store` (you can check that on the command line by running `ls /Library/Caches/com.apple.iconservices.store`, this will either list the content of the directory if it exists, or display an error message if it doesn't exist) then you can't directly use `mv` to restore the old content. Instead you need to move or remove the current version and immediately afterwards move the version you want to restore.

The `rm` command deletes the files. You can't bring them back except by restoring from a backup. On the flip side, they'll stop using up disk space.